# Blender file export fail to .stl to Cura for 3D printing

Tags: modifiers, 3d-printing, stl

I got my Neptune 3D printer setup. I was able to print the test model Buddha and it looks great! Super excited.

I designed an object in Blender that has mesh layers and uses a couple of Boolean modifiers.

I exported the blender file using: Export < .stl < (name contains no spaces or special characters). When I attempt to open the file using the Cura software I get error messages and a grey shadow. Very frustrated because I spent a lot of time learning the blender controls and tools and this is not making me happy. Cube has hollowed out portion, 20mm x 20mm x 20mm.

- Any suggestions?[image]
  [image]

Comment: Can you edit your post and attach your .blend file please. https://blend-exchange.com/  
Also, activate the 3D Printing Toolbox addon (ships with Blender) and use it's tools to check the object for any problems.

Comment: Also... Cura has automatically scaled your STL. Meaning that it probably exported extremely small. This can happen when you think you are working in millimeters, but have the scene Unit Scale still set to 1.0, when it should be set to 0.001

Comment: I’m sorry if you’re disappointed in Blender. Aside from relay to you information we have collected from free documentations or paid courses, we can’t do any more about any problems you might encounter than you can: Most BStEx users are not Blender developers.

Comment: Right off the bat, I’m thinking that you set it to export selected objects only or something, and only a tiny component is selected. I’ve never heard of mesh layers, so I have no info on wether or not the STL exporter can handle them correctly. I might check that part of the component isn’t actually imported, but is very high up, outside the print volume, and is thus causing an error. The shadow looks wrong regardless, so it’s probably not exporting correctly, but to see what did export would help a lot I think.

Comment: Make sure the normals are facing the right way. In edit mode select everything then go Mesh > Normls > Recalculate Outside